# I have some problems with this Java code, and am getting errors

Tags: java

When I run my code, it displays an error message code.

I tried to write a code which permits to create a class, with the creation of cities("Ville" in French), with a private access.

My code is the following :

```
package apprentissage_open_classrooms;

public class Ville {
      public Ville(){

              private String nomVille;
              private String nomPays;
              private int nbreHabitants;
      }
                System.out.println("Création d'une ville !");          
                nomVille = "Inconnu";
                nomPays = "Inconnu";
                nbreHabitants = 0;

              public Ville(String pNom, int pNbre, String pPays)
              {
                System.out.println("Création d'une ville avec des paramètres !");
                nomVille = pNom;
                nomPays = pPays;
                nbreHabitants = pNbre;
              }        
          public String getNom()  {  
            return nomVille;
          }
          public String getNomPays()
          {
            return nomPays;
          }
          public int getNombreHabitants()
          {
            return nbreHabitants;
          } 
          public void setNom(String pNom)
          {
            nomVille = pNom;
          }
          public void setNomPays(String pPays)
          {
            nomPays = pPays;
          }
          public void setNombreHabitants(int nbre)
          {
            nbreHabitants = nbre;
          }  
        }
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Your default constructor's ending bracket closed too early.

Comment: The variable declarations for `nomVille` etc. need to before the constructor and the brace before the constructor needs to be removed.

Comment: `private` is not allowed in variables (e.g. inside method or constructor) like in `private String nomVille;`

Comment: It's okay, the probleme is solved, I had just to inverse two parts of my code. Thank you very much for your excellent advice, Shabbir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's giving error because your are trying to write a statement "System.out.println("Création d'une ville !");" independently inside a class, which is not allowed(It must be inside a block), you can only do member declaration or initialisation directly inside a class.

You just did mistake into placing this section of code independent`

```
System.out.println("Création d'une ville !");          
nomVille = "Inconnu";
nomPays = "Inconnu";
nbreHabitants = 0;`
```

And this part into no-args constructor.

```
          private String nomVille;
          private String nomPays;
          private int nbreHabitants;
```

But, It should be just opposite. So, to correct yourself, Just put these above declaration lines before no-args constructor and initialisation part into default constructor, Just like what you are doing in parameterized constructor.